# Responsive CSS3 Transition Dropdown Nav Menu blip

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having a problem with my ccs3 transition for a website I am working on.

You can view the site here.
http://cornergrillny.com/index2.php

I almost have it working if you resize down to mobile view it looks great.

But, on desktop there is a small glitch I would like to fix.

Notice, when you resize the browser less then 1000 pixels because the css3 adjusting the max-height to 0 hiding the nav it slides up and looks funny.

I cannot use display:none because ccs3 transition needs a "height" attribute to show the nav sliding up and down.

Simple fix? Been bugging me for an hour.

I will post the fixed code on here

Thanks in advance.
-O

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS alone won't help here. Use JQuery's slideUp() & slideDown() functions to get the effect you want.
Quick concept:

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("open")){
    $(".menu").slideUp();
    $(this).removeClass("open");
  }else{
    $(".menu").slideDown();
    $(this).addClass("open");
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrap .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrap .menu {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrap .button {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .wrap .button {
    display: none;
  }
}
.wrap li, .wrap .button {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrap li, .wrap .button {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="button">[#]</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example here: http://codepen.io/flowbob/pen/mymqvp

Comment: The css transition is only in the 1004 < media query.. but on the break it resizes the nav max-height to 0, and because of the css style u see the animation... i want to remove that animation.. if I remove the style there would be no animation

Comment: OK. Now i got you. As you're already using JQuery, you can use slideUp() and slideDown() for your menu. I quickly built a working concept for you: http://codepen.io/flowbob/pen/mymqvp